# The five-year rule and backdoor Roth IRA conversions with non-deductible contributions

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, penalty, roth-conversion

I have a Roth IRA that was opened and initially funded more than five years ago. Now that I'm earning too much money to make regular contributions, I'd like to further fund this account through a backdoor conversion. If I open a new traditional IRA, fund it with a non-deductible contribution, and convert it into my existing Roth IRA (and file Form 8606), will I be able to safely withdraw that contribution at a later date without being subject to the 10% penalty?

Backdoor Roth IRA conversions make sense but the five-year rule is confusing me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Backdoor conversion is **not** a contribution.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking, and what I'm worried about. Is it a contribution, or is it something else? Can I withdraw it like a contribution if I start with non-deductible traditional IRA contributions?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the conversion was completely non-taxable (i.e. your Traditional IRA was 100% basis), then the converted money can be taken out at any time whatsoever (no 5 year or age stuff), without tax or penalty, similar to directly contributed money. For withdrawing conversions and rollovers within 5 years of the conversion or rollover, the penalty only applies to the part of the conversion or rollover that was taxable. Since in this case the conversion was completely non-taxable, there is no penalty on the withdrawal.

However, note that the *ordering* of the conversion money is not the same as for contribution money, and this may be significant in some cases. When you take money out of Roth IRA, it goes 1) contributions, 2) rollovers and conversions, and 3) earnings. However, money within (2) is then further divided by year, with rollovers and contributions for earlier years ordered before rollovers and contributions for later years, and then within each year, the taxable rollover and conversion money are ordered first, before the non-taxable money.

So what does that mean? Well, suppose you made a Roth IRA conversion that was taxable one year, and then the next year you make a contribution. If you withdraw a little bit, it comes from the contribution which is ordered first, which means no penalty. Now suppose in that second year you had a backdoor Roth IRA contribution instead of a regular contribution. If you withdraw, the first year's conversion is ordered first, and since it's within 5 years, there's a penalty. It's still true that withdrawing the backdoor Roth IRA has no penalty; but, you don't get to that money until you finish the other one. If you've never made a taxable conversion before, then this issue doesn't exist.

Comment: Interesting explanation, but can you cite an authoritative source? As I remarked, this makes the conversion a way to avoid pre-59-1/2 penalty if this is the case.

Comment: Non-authoritative source that supports some of the statements: http://www.paychex.com/a/d/white-papers/advisors/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-5-year-rule-for-roth-iras.pdf

Comment: Authoritative source: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b/ch02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000231064

Answer (score 2):

For conversions you do not to be 59-1/2 to avoid penalty. The 5-yr rule thus creates an early withdrawal option if planned well in advance.

See the flow chart in http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000231030
For where I sourced the answer.

Note : I edited to correct my answer. User102008 called me out on my mistake, and rightly so. The dialog is in the comments, where he points out the mistake. Good job, new User.

Comment: I believe you're referring to the age requirement on distributions of earnings. I'm asking about contributions, not earnings.

Comment: Your normal deposits can be withdrawn any time. I answered how the five year rule applies to a conversion. Back door Roth is a converted traditional IRA.

Comment: This is not correct. The penalty would only apply to the part of the conversion that was taxable. An ideal backdoor Roth IRA contribution, where you convert immediately after the Traditional IRA contribution, will be 100% non-deductible, and thus have no taxable part in the conversion. Thus, there will be no penalty when you withdraw the conversion.

Comment: @user102008 - IRS regs regarding IRAs are not 100% clear to me. Can you cite a source for your position? Your comment implies that a 40 yr old converts, and at 45 can now withdraw Roth money with no (10%) penalty. Thus completely avoiding the 59-1/2 rule. I'm open to this being the case, would just like a citation.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Well, do you have a source that there's a penalty? Here is the source on penalty (additional tax) for Roth IRA early distributions: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000231064 For distribution of conversions within a 5-year period, "You generally must pay the 10% additional tax on any amount attributable to the part of the amount converted or rolled over (the conversion or rollover contribution) that you had to include in income (recapture amount)." A backdoor Roth IRA conversion has no amount that had to be included in income.

Comment: yes, that was what i linked to.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: so you agree?

Comment: No. You asked me to cite source, and I replied I had already done so. Please tell me why you think I'm reading Figure 2-1 incorrectly. Please note, I am 51, and would love to have you be right.

Comment: http://fairmark.com/retirement/roth-accounts/roth-distributions/distributions-after-a-roth-ira-conversion/ supports your position.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: There is nothing wrong with Figure 2-1. The distribution is a non-qualified distribution. That is not in dispute. That doesn't mean it has a penalty. The part of non-qualified distributions that come from contributions and the non-taxable part of conversions and rollovers do not have penalty.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: If you have never had a Roth IRA before, and you contribute say $5000 to a Roth IRA, and two years later you decide to withdraw $5000, for no reason, and you are not 59, there will be no tax or penalty, because your entire distribution came from contributions. This is well established. Are you in agreement with this? Now, given this, the question is asking whether a backdoor Roth IRA contribution (i.e. you contribute to a Traditional IRA and then immediately convert to a Roth IRA) works the same way. My answer is that it does, with minor differences in ordering.

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight. You are indeed correct.